# Calling java.lang.String .split methode in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

When i call the `.split` methode in clojure i get: `#object["[Ljava.lang.String;" 0x5aaf6982 "[Ljava.lang.String;@5aaf6982"] #object["[Ljava.lang.String;" 0x18fbbda2 "[Ljava.lang.String;@18fbbda2"]`.
How can i use this object in my code?

Comment: this is how i call `.split`: `(.split "1,2,3,4,5" ",")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `vec` to convert a Java array into a vector, e.g.

```
(vec (.split "1,2,3,4,5" ","))
=> ["1" "2" "3" "4" "5"]
```

But really if you want to split a string into a Clojure collection you should be using `clojure.string/split` instead:

```
(clojure.string/split "1,2,3,4,5" #",")
=> ["1" "2" "3" "4" "5"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using `.split` method of Java `String` class, then the result is a Java array.

You can use [aget](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/aget) function of Clojure to access the elements.

And depending on your use case, it might be better to convert the array into Clojure sequence, so you can use a vast array of functions that Clojure provides to manipulate sequences.

Comment: how could i invoke the whole resulting elements as a sequence? Is there a built-in function? I assume `aget` let me access the elements only via index?

Comment: @AmirTeymuri The link I provided explains `aget`.